# php MYSQL query "ORDER BY" not working

Tags: php, mysql, sorting, variables

Forewarning: I'm sure my code is clunky and inefficient, please feel free to call me out on it. I'm fairly new at this.

I'm attempting to order my query results by a column, indicated as a result of a select input. The select input exists on *feed.php* which features `include: 'feedphp2.php`.

The select input auto-submits *onchange* with `action="feedSort.php"`. *feedSort.php* takes the submitted value and redirects to `feed.php?sort=submittedValue`. Then the included *feedphp2.php* within *feed.php* takes the `$_GET['sort']` value and pulls a query sorted by that column.

**//feed.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['userID'])) {
        header('Location: login.html');
}

?>

<html>
<head>
<title>Title</title>

<link href="style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css
family=Josefin+Sans:400,100,300,600,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>

<body style="background-color:rgba(0,212,242,0.1)">

<div class="headerSmall">
    <div class="container">
        <a href="index.php"><img class="logoImgSmall"
src="images/logosmall2.png"></a>
        <div class="navFeed">
            <?php include 'usernameGet.php';?>,<a 
href="sessionDestroy.php">Log Out</a>
            <a href="addMeal.php">List a Meal</a>
            <a href="dashboardBought.php">Dashboard</a>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>

<div class="container">


    <div class="sort">
    <form action="feedSort.php" method="POST">
        <select name="sortForm" onchange="this.form.submit()">
            <option value="">Sort By...</option>
            <option value="user">By User</option>
            <option value="dateAdded">By Date Added</option>


        </select>
    </form>
    </div>

    <?php include 'feedphp2.php'?>


</div>


</body>
</html>
```

space

**//feedphp2.php**

```
<?php
include 'MysqlConnect.php';
mysqli_select_db($conn,$dbname);

if (isset($_GET['sort'])) {
    $sortBy = $_GET['sort'];

    echo $sortBy;

    $resultQuery = "SELECT * FROM meals
    ORDER BY '$sortBy'";

} else {
    echo 'sortBy is not set.';
    $resultQuery = "SELECT * FROM meals
    ORDER BY user";
}

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $resultQuery);

//Write to divs
while ($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

    $imgSrc = $rows['image']; 

    echo '<a href="meal.php?'.'mealID=';
    echo $rows['ID'];
    echo '">';

    echo '<div class="entry">';
    echo '<div class="foodPic">';
    echo '<img src="';

    echo $imgSrc;

    echo '">';
    echo '</div>';
    echo '<p class="entryName">'.$rows['mealName'].'</p>';
    echo '<p class="entryServ">'.$rows['mealQuan'].'</p>';
    echo '<p 
   class="entryPrice">$'.$rows['mealDollars'].'.'.$rows['mealCents'].'</p>';
    echo '<img class="servingsIco" src="images/servings.png">';

    echo '<p class="user">'.$rows['user'].'</p>';
    echo '</div>';
    echo '</a>';
}

?>
```

space
**//feedSort.php:**

```
<?php
session_start();
$sortBy = $_POST['sortForm'];

header ("Location: feed.php?sort=".$sortBy."");
?>
```

Columns within my table exist for both `user` and `dateAdded` and sort perfectly when explicitly provided within the query ie: `SELECT * FROM meals
ORDER BY user`. While provided through a PHP variable however:

Where `$sortBy = user` returns the exact same sort order as `$sortBy = dateAdded`.

I appreciate any help you might provide.

Comment: Try it without the quotes, ie. `" ... SORT BY $sortby"`

Comment: You're mixing up the globals $_POST and $_GET. Also note that your code is vulnerable to injection!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you using $_POST method to pass the value and using $_GET method to retrieve it . and change the $sortby without quotes. edit these lines in your feedphp2.php

```
<?php
include 'MysqlConnect.php';
mysqli_select_db($conn,$dbname);
if (isset($_POST['sort'])) {
    $sortBy = $_POST['sort'];
    echo $sortBy;
    $resultQuery = "SELECT * FROM meals
    ORDER BY $sortBy";

} else {
```

or use $_REQUEST[],Method which will retrieve both get and post method

```
<?php
include 'MysqlConnect.php';
mysqli_select_db($conn,$dbname);
if (isset($_REQUEST['sort'])) {//request method
    $sortBy = $_REQUEST['sort'];//
    echo $sortBy;
    $resultQuery = "SELECT * FROM meals
    ORDER BY $sortBy";

} else {
```

Comment: I'm using $_POST to pass the select input to a url '?sort=value', then $_GET to retrieve it. Is that wrong? And when quotes are removed from $sortBy it returns: Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in

Comment: what it is passsing in the get method?feed.php?sort=".$sortBy."? what value is passing

Comment: Just figured it out. The value for input was 'dateAdded' while my column name was 'timeAdded'. But that was the secondary problem, you fixed my first one. Cheers! Much appreciated

Comment: hmmm :) happy to help you.